# Inserting string into a literal in the masterpage always fails in Chrome but sometimes works in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, browser

I can't for the life of me see what the problem is... Works in one browser but not another? Both browsers are the latest versions.

When I say it doesn't work I mean that the first load of the page/control there is nothing inserted, on subsequent refreshes is where the strange behaviour appears; nothing is ever in the literal in chrome etc no matter how many postbacks occur, but in FireFox, first page load there is nothing, then after a postback there is text in the literal?

Full cache clears of chrome doesn't seem to work either.

In Masterpage

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            <asp:Literal id="ExtraScripts" runat="server" />

        });
    </script>
</head>
```

In myControl.ascx.cs

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "$(\".select2\").select2();";

    Literal litExtraScripts = (Literal)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ExtraScripts");

    if (concatenate)
    {
        litExtraScripts.Text += script ;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I've even tested this in every event of the page cycle and it seems to always work when debugging the code until you look at what is rendered and like I said, nothing in Chrome etc, FireFox shows something after a postback only.

The console window is blank, not even any 'issues'.

The project makes use of Telerik Web UI and AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @BadPiggie Nope, nothing, not even any 'issues'.

Comment: and where does/did the var concatenate come from, and how did it get setup?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I am basically using a standard method to use the publicly available drop down list jQuery script named Select2.